# How do i give a path to testrunner script into my TeamCity docker container?

Tags: docker, teamcity, soapui, test-runner

Basically i want to run my SoapUI tests (ReadyAPI is downloaded on my computer). With Teamcity, which is running in docker container.

So i started my Teamcity server and agent in docker container. Like this: https://strangeway.org/2017/12/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC-teamcity-%D1%81-docker/

After that i installed SoapUI pro plugin (SoapUI Pro Functional Testing) into my teamcity server.

To start a build in Teamciy using SoapUI Pro Functional Testing it is mandatory to give a path to testrunner shell script into Teamcity server.

My question is: how do i give path to a shell script that is located on my computer to a Teamcity server that is running inside a docker container?

Answer (score 0):

hard way.

map your local directory to your TeamCity container. 
use this volume(inside the container) in your test build step

best way

store your tests to VCS like git. 
add VSC roots to TeamCity Server 
attach VCS to your build 
use files in the build steps